# Define fonts in theme.json what slug name

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

Is there a naming convention for slugs for fontFamilies in `themes.json`. I see they end up being using for the vss var `--wp--preset--font-family--<slug>`. So it would make sense to name the slug something generic like `body-text` instead of for instance `open-sans`, where a child theme might use a different font family but with the same, generic slug.

Example

### Rationale

The slug is only used by the theme developer, not by the web designer. The web designer selects the font from a list of fonts made available by the theme developer.